Understanding symbol of a latching push switch
I want to understand the schematic symbol for the illuminated, latching push switch I am using. My objective is to use it simply for ON and OFF purposes.
Link for the part and datasheet.
Symbol from the datasheet:



Connect L1 and L2 to light the LED.  V+ goes to L1, V- goes to L2.
When the button is up, pins 1 and 2 are connected together and pins 4 and 5 are connected together.
When the button is down, pins 2 and 3 are connected together and pins 5 and 6 are connected together.

To use it as a power switch (maximum of 50 mA and 12VDC,) connect pins 2 and 3 in series with your power supply.  When the button is up, the conection will be open - the device is off.  When the button is down, pins 2 and 3 will be connected together - the device is on.
Connect pins L1 and L2 to a part of the powered circuit.  You will need a series resistor to limit current to the LED.  The datasheet doesn't mention the current rating for the LED.  I'd go with just a few milliamperes.

Understood, thank you so much. Yeah, I couldn't find the LED specs. So I have considered 2.2V to be Vf and 20mA to be the forward current.
